# Как проксировать nginx'сом на https сервер nodejs

Tags: node.js, nginx, https, proxy

Сейчас так: файлы сертификата указаны в конфиге nginx'са, на бэкенде сервер http на nodejs, всё хорошо, сайт доступен по https.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domen.com www.domen.com;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}

listen 443 ssl; 
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domen.com/fullchain.pem; 
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domen.com/privkey.pem;
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; 
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;


}
```

это конфиг nginx.

а вот сам ноде:

```
const http = require('http');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
res.writeHead(200);
res.end('ok');
});

server.listen(8000);
```

всё тут хорошо, domen.com доступен по https,

но появилась необходимость использовать https сервер на node, в самом сервере указываю сертификаты и т.д., в конфиге nginx'а убераю всё что связанно с ssl, в итоге по заходу на сайт пишет не верный ответ сертификата, а в firefox'е мол ответ превышает максимальную длину, хотя если с локалки заходить на https ервер ноды то прекрасно показывает https соединение (если по локалхосту то не действителен сертификат, я прописал в файле host название домена и теперь можно обращаться по домену как по локалхосту или ipшнику внутреннему)

т.е. когда конфиг такой

```
server {
listen 443;
 server_name domen.com www.domen.com;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:8000/;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_set_header host $host;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For     
 $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}

}
```

а ноде такой:

```
const https = require('https');
const fs = require('fs');

const options = {
key: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/domen.com/privkey.pem'),
cert: fs.readFileSync('/etc/letsencrypt/live/domen.com/fullchain.pem')
};

https.createServer(options, (req, res) => {
 res.writeHead(200);
 res.end('ok');
}).listen(8000);
```

по заходу с внешки пишет чо ответ сертификата не верный, отя из локальной сети заходит и показывает htpps оединение и всё ок

так вот, как настроить nginx чтоб он проксировал на https сервер node, так чтоб не было выше указанных ошибок, чтоб было обычное https соединение заходя с внешки?

Comment: 1. все конфиги в студию 2. поправьте этот поток мыслей, если не сложно, на более дружественный

Comment: сейчас поправлю

Comment: Надо прочитать какой-нибудь ликбез о том как работает https и почему то что вы сделали работать не может по определению.

Comment: оно может работать, если убрать nginx как прокси и самой нодой слушать 80 порт, т.е. на прямую сделать

Comment: но nginx нужен...

Comment: @shol порт 80 и https в одном предложении не сочетаются. Наверное всё-таки 443.

Comment: Ну так оставьте в nginx все сертификаты и просто поменяйте в proxy_pass http на https. И включите keep-alive между nginx и приложением

Comment: т.е. оставить сертификаты и в ноде и в nginx'е ?

Comment: Да. Появятся мелкие накладные расходы на шифрование nginx->нода, но при грамотной настройке это не страшно

Comment: Ну или поднять в ноде два сервера, http и https

Comment: да, проблема решена, как сказал Алексей Тен надо было и там и там сертификты оставить, теперь всё замечательно, жаль что никаким образом не сделать так, чтоб не править конфиг прокси сервера, всё равно там нужны сертификаты